# Does Django Channels uses ws:// protocol prefix to route between Django view or Channels app?

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, daphne

I am running Django + Channels server using Daphne. Daphne server is behind Nginx. My Nginx config looks like as given at end.

When I try to connect to `ws://example.com/ws/endpoint` I am getting `NOT FOUNT /ws/endpoint` error.

For me, it looks like Daphne is using protocol to route to either Django views or Channels app. If it sees `http` it routes to Django view and when it sees `ws` it routes to Channels app.

With following Nginx proxy pass configuration the URL always has `http` protocol prefix. So I am getting 404 or NOT FOUND in logs. If I change proxy_pass prefix to `ws` Nginx config fails.

What is the ideal way to setup Channels in the this scenario?

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com

    location / {

        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

        # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8088;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        # enables WS support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_read_timeout 999999999;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as in the question Channels detects the route based on the protocol header `ws` or `http/https`

Using `ws` prefix in `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000/;` is not possible. To forward the protocol information following config should be included.

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

This will forward the schema/protocol(`ws`) information to Channels app. And channels routes according to this information.